# Custom authentication provider not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to have a custom authentication provider where I would like to have a keycloak as an authenticator.
Have created just a simple class for authentication provider but its not being called.

```
@Component
public class CustomKeycloakAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) 
      throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = auth.getName();
        String password = auth.getCredentials()
            .toString();

        if ("externaluser".equals(username) && "pass".equals(password)) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
              (username, password, Collections.emptyList());
        } else {
            throw new 
              BadCredentialsException("External system authentication failed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> auth) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(auth));
    }
}
```

Here is my WebConfig class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
//@EnableMyHttpSession
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    private AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomKeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager)
                // .antMatchers("/oauth/token", "/*.html", "/js/**", "/images/**",
                // "/styles/**").permitAll().
                .antMatchers("/service/*").fullyAuthenticated()
                // .antMatchers("/reports/*").fullyAuthenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean(name = "authenticationManagerBean")
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

    @Bean
    public AffirmativeBased accessDecisionManager() {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<?>> accessDecisionVoters = new ArrayList<>();
        accessDecisionVoters.add(new ScopeVoter());
        accessDecisionVoters.add(new RoleVoter());
        accessDecisionVoters.add(new AuthenticatedVoter());

        AffirmativeBased accessDecisionManager = new AffirmativeBased(accessDecisionVoters);
        return accessDecisionManager;
    }
```

I also have a Authorization Server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
 
    
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthorizationServerConfiguration.class);
    
    //private static String REALM="MY_OAUTH_REALM";
     
    
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dateSource;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;
 
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomClientBuilder customClientBuilder;
    
    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;
    
    
    @Autowired
    public UserService userService;
    
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomClientService customClientService;

    @Autowired
    private AccessRightsService accessRightService;

    private MyTokenServices tokenServices = null;
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MyTokenServices tokenServices() {
        if(tokenServices != null) return tokenServices;
        tokenServices = new MyTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(customClientService);
        tokenServices.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        tokenServices.userService = userService;
        tokenServices.accessRightService = accessRightService;
        return tokenServices;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public TokenStore tokenStore( @Value("${oauth2Token.store.type}") String tokenStoreType) {
        TokenStore tokenStore =  null;
        log.info("Token store is type " + tokenStoreType);
        if(tokenStoreType.toLowerCase().equals("jdbc")){
            tokenStore = new JdbcTokenStore(dateSource);
        }else {
            tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();
        }
        log.info("Token store is " + tokenStore);
        return tokenStore;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.setBuilder(customClientBuilder);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .tokenServices(tokenServices())
                .userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptorAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse rs, Object o) throws Exception {
                        rs.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                        rs.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
                        rs.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
                        rs.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
                        log.info(hsr.getMethod());
                        if(hsr.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")){
                            rs.setStatus(200); // hard fix for options
                        }
                        return true;
                        }
                    });
        
 
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
      oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }
```

When I try to do a login in the providers there are only 2 of them:
[image]

I have tried to put @Autowired to protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) { but it didn't helped
Don't know if there is something in configuration that I am missing so it doesn't add the 3rd authentication provider.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Security keyclaock can be configured with a class that derive of KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

(https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>20.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I think you don't need to create your own AuthenticationProvider keycloak give you an implementation *KeycloakAuthenticationProvider*

**Update OK (but why ?) :**

So I think you don't need to override that method

```
@Override
 protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
```

Create another one like this

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I have just named the variables like that, but don't want to use it, just want to create a custom authentication provider.